# How to fetch and update products from/to salesforce using php?

Tags: php, magento, salesforce

```
<?php
define("USERNAME", "abc@demo.com");
define("PASSWORD", "abc");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "aDyy0oukYSCsQ7qua7lgG85Jd");

require_once ('includes/soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');




 $client = new SoapClient('http://url/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');

 $session = $client->login('ab', 'ab');

$result = $client->call($session, 'order.list');

echo "\n\n";

$mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection("includes/soapclient/partner.wsdl.xml");
$mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

echo "<br><br>";

foreach($result as $res)
{
$records = array();
//print_r($result);

$records[0] = new stdClass();
$records[0]->fields = array(
    'FirstName' => $res['firstname'] ,
    'LastName' => $res['lastname'],
    'Email' => $res['customer_email'] 
);
$records[0]->type = 'Contact';
$response = $mySforceConnection->create($records);
/*
print_r($response);
//echo "Full Record=". $res . "<br/>";
echo "<br/> Customer Details:<br/>";
echo "FirstName=". $res['firstname'] . "<br/>";
echo "LastName=". $res['lastname'] . "<br/>";
echo "Email=". $res['customer_email'] . "<br/>";
*/
}



$ids = array();
foreach ($response as $i => $result) {
   /* echo $records[$i]->fields["FirstName"] . " "
            . $records[$i]->fields["LastName"] . " "
            . $result->id . "<br/>\n";*/
    array_push($ids, $result->id);

}


 ?>
```

This code works fine for inserting data into salesforce and I am also able to get the contacts to my website.
But I was not able to figure out that how to fetch products in my website and update it in salesforce as well.

Please Help ...

Thanks

Comment: afaik is salesforce a large CRM, isn't there a magento module for it?!

Comment: well I am not aware of that.  But if you can suggest me I will take a look at it.. Thanks.

Comment: wow. I found one for orders: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/integrations/crm/magenforce.html But not for products. I should write one :D

Comment: Well if you create one do not forget to share it.. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Products are stored in `Product2` table and the best place to check which fields are there would be your WSDL or a describe call.

Online explanation "what is what" is available only for standard fields (obviously, if you've created some custom ones they won't be in the docs): http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_product2.htm

To fetch them you'd have to use [`query()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_query.htm?SearchType=Stem) call, something like this should get you started:

```
$queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name, ProductCode FROM Product2 ORDER BY Name LIMIT 10';
$products= $mySforceConnection -> query($queryString);
print_r($products);
```

Read further in the docs from the last link about update statements and you should be able to connect all the dots :)

Comment: one Question why product name is updating in magento <sf:Name>Procuct Name</sf:Name>  like this.? I dont want <sf:name> in there.

Comment: Weird, looks like XML parser didn't deal with the tags correctly. Does it happen only for products or with any Name field? Run couple more selects like `SELECT Id, Name FROM Account` or Opportunity maybe? Maybe something in the SforcePartnerClient has to be updated to new API version (SF is now on version 26, older ones should still work though). What version do you have on the bottom of the partner.wsdl.xml file?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do.Update product name from salesforce to magento. and it works perfect but when i echo $aa it gives simply product name but when i use it in following code and update the product, it renames it by <sf:Name>Procuct Name</sf:Name>. $result5 = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.update', array('sku', array(
   
    'name' => $aa

))); I am doing this manually I would like to know how can we achieve this automatically i.e., if any product is added to salesforce it should be added to magento as well and vice versa without using any cron jobs. A perfect web service.